# linq - find item in list within multiple lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a highly nested class, and trying to find a single item buried deep within. The following gives me an error "Can't convert type match to bool', although I don't see why it thinks I'm trying to return a boolean.

```
var match = community.TeamLeagues
   .Where(x => x.Seasons
       .Where(y => y.Divisions
           .Where(z => z.Matches
               .Where(a => a.Id == "1234").FirstOrDefault())));
```

Comment: The third `Where` expects a `bool`(what divisions should i return). But you return the first _Match_ with the `Id` 1234. The `Match` is not a `bool`, so the compiler complains.

Comment: Won't a `var match = community.TeamLeagues.Where(x => x.Seasons.Divisions.Matches.Id == "1234")` be possible? Then select the entities you need

Comment: No, Seasons and Divisions are also lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get it working with linq, but works with query syntax.

```
var leagueMatch = (from teamLeague in community.TeamLeagues
                from season in teamLeague.Seasons
                from division in season.Divisions
                from match in division.Matches.Where(x => x.Id == "1234")
                select match).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 4):

`Where` by itself returns a (deferred) enumerable of items and cannot as such be used as a condition by the outer `Where`. What you probably want to do is to use `Contains()`, `Any()` or `All()` inside the outer `Where`s that will return the result you're looking for.

Something like this might be what you're after:

```
var match = community.TeamLeagues.Where(t =>
        t.Seasons.Any(
        s => s.Divisions.Any(
        d => d.Matches.Any(
        m => m.Id == "1234")
        )));
```

Comment: I thought that worked, but it's actually returning type TeamLeague, not type Match which I need

Comment: @BMills: Are you looking for matches? You didn't mention that in the post. Also it looks like `Id` is the unique key of `Match` class, so filtering on `m.Id == "1234"` will result in one `Match` at most, which you can find directly too by using a simple, one-level `Where` on your `Matches` collection (if u have one), instead of nesting it 5 levels deep.

Answer (score 1):

The `Where` method needs to evaluate an expression that returns a `bool`. Your nested `Where`s are not doing that - the only Where that is, is the last one `a => a.Id == "1234"`, all the other expressions are returning an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

`z.Matches.Where(a => a.Id == "1234").FirstOrDefault()` returns a object of type `Match`(your collection item type of the IEnumerable `Matches`) (or null), no boolean value. I guess you need to check if there are entires in matches that have a Id 1234. Use `Any` to evaluate a condition:

```
var match = community.TeamLeagues.Where(x => 
              x.Seasons.Any(y => 
                y.Divisions.Any(z => 
                   z.Matches.Any(a => a.Id == "1234")
            )));
```

[`items.Where(x => x.Id == 4).Any()` is the same as `items.Any(x => x.Id == 4)`]

This returns you all TeamLeagues which contain a Season which contain a Division which contain a Match which has a element with the id 1234.

Comment: He uses `FirstOrDefault` after the `Where`. So still not a `bool` though

Comment: Modified my example to mention FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple you can also use the `Matches` table directly and using a ViewModel you can represent your view.

like:
     var MyViewModel = (from l in Mathes
                           where l.Id == "1234"
                           select new MyViewModel
                          {
                               Id = l.Id,
                               MatchName = l.Name,
                            }).ToList();